# Fix on Weird Vertical Alignment of Multicols

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol

What I have is the following code.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
            \toprule
            \(k\) & \(x_{k}\) & \(y_{k}\) & \(x_{k}y_{k}\) & \(x_{k}^{2}\) \\
            \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
            \(1\) & \(0\) & \(2\) & \(0(2)\) & \(0^{2}\) \\
            \(2\) & \(1\) & \(3\) & \(1(3)\) & \(1^{2}\) \\
            \(3\) & \(2\) & \(5\) & \(2(5)\) & \(2^{2}\) \\
            \(4\) & \(3\) & \(4\) & \(3(4)\) & \(3^{2}\) \\
            \(5\) & \(4\) & \(6\) & \(4(6)\) & \(4^{2}\) \\
            \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
            \(\sum\nolimits\) & \({\color{Salmon}10}\) & \({\color{Salmon}20}\) & \({\color{Salmon}49}\) & \({\color{Salmon}30}\) \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \columnbreak
    \begin{align*}
        \alpha &= \frac{
            \det\begin{pmatrix}
                \color{Salmon}30 & \color{Salmon}49 \\
                \color{Salmon}10 & \color{Salmon}20
            \end{pmatrix}
        }{
            \det\begin{pmatrix}
                \color{Salmon}30 & \color{Salmon}10 \\
                \color{Salmon}10 & 5
            \end{pmatrix}
        } & \beta &= \frac{
            \det\begin{pmatrix}
                \color{Salmon}49 & \color{Salmon}10 \\
                \color{Salmon}20 & 5
            \end{pmatrix}
        }{
            \det\begin{pmatrix}
                \color{Salmon}30 & \color{Salmon}10 \\
                \color{Salmon}10 & 5
            \end{pmatrix}
        } \\
        &= \frac{30(20)-10(49)}{30(5)-10(10)} & &= \frac{49(5)-20(10)}{30(5)-10(10)} \\
        &= 2.2, & &= 0.9.
    \end{align*}
\end{multicols}
```

The code above compiles `multicols` as I attached below.

[image]

However, I want it to be vertically centred. How can I achieve that? I'm looking for any alternative, not necessarily to use `multicols`. I'd also appreciate it if the fix either centring both the table and equation vertically or horizontally, which I have zero clue to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off-topic: By using an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, you could save yourself from having to input 7*5 = 35 instances of both `\(` and `\)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `multicols` for printing things side-by-side is not the right tool: `multicols` is meant to print longer text in multiple columns.

You can use `\[...\]`, with an `array` and `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
  \toprule
  k & x_{k} & y_{k} & x_{k}y_{k} & x_{k}^{2} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
  1 & 0 & 2 & 0(2) & 0^{2} \\
  2 & 1 & 3 & 1(3) & 1^{2} \\
  3 & 2 & 5 & 2(5) & 2^{2} \\
  4 & 3 & 4 & 3(4) & 3^{2} \\
  5 & 4 & 6 & 4(6) & 4^{2} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
  \sum & \color{Salmon}10 & \color{Salmon}20 & \color{Salmon}49 & \color{Salmon}30 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}
  \alpha &= \frac{
              \det\begin{pmatrix}
                \color{Salmon}30 & \color{Salmon}49 \\
                \color{Salmon}10 & \color{Salmon}20
              \end{pmatrix}
            }{
              \det\begin{pmatrix}
                \color{Salmon}30 & \color{Salmon}10 \\
                \color{Salmon}10 & 5
              \end{pmatrix}
             } &
  \beta &= \frac{
             \det\begin{pmatrix}
               \color{Salmon}49 & \color{Salmon}10 \\
               \color{Salmon}20 & 5
             \end{pmatrix}
           }{
             \det\begin{pmatrix}
               \color{Salmon}30 & \color{Salmon}10 \\
               \color{Salmon}10 & 5
             \end{pmatrix}
           } \\
        &= \frac{30(20)-10(49)}{30(5)-10(10)} & &= \frac{49(5)-20(10)}{30(5)-10(10)} \\
        &= 2.2, & &= 0.9.
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also exploit that the two alignments on the right side have similar shapes, so easing the input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
  \toprule
  k & x_{k} & y_{k} & x_{k}y_{k} & x_{k}^{2} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
  1 & 0 & 2 & 0(2) & 0^{2} \\
  2 & 1 & 3 & 1(3) & 1^{2} \\
  3 & 2 & 5 & 2(5) & 2^{2} \\
  4 & 3 & 4 & 3(4) & 3^{2} \\
  5 & 4 & 6 & 4(6) & 4^{2} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
  \sum & \color{Salmon}10 & \color{Salmon}20 & \color{Salmon}49 & \color{Salmon}30 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}
  \alpha &= \frac{
              \det\begin{pmatrix}
                \color{Salmon}30 & \color{Salmon}49 \\
                \color{Salmon}10 & \color{Salmon}20
              \end{pmatrix}
            }{
              \det\begin{pmatrix}
                \color{Salmon}30 & \color{Salmon}10 \\
                \color{Salmon}10 & 5
              \end{pmatrix}
             } \\
  &= \frac{30(20)-10(49)}{30(5)-10(10)} \\
  &= 2.2
\end{aligned}
\quad
\begin{aligned}
  \beta &= \frac{
             \det\begin{pmatrix}
               \color{Salmon}49 & \color{Salmon}10 \\
               \color{Salmon}20 & 5
             \end{pmatrix}
           }{
             \det\begin{pmatrix}
               \color{Salmon}30 & \color{Salmon}10 \\
               \color{Salmon}10 & 5
             \end{pmatrix}
           } \\
  &= \frac{49(5)-20(10)}{30(5)-10(10)} \\
  &= 0.9.
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the very big help and insight.

Answer (score 0):

Using the machinery of the `multicol` package seems like overkill for the use case at hand. I would like to suggest that you place an `array` environment on the left (no need to encase it in a `table` environment) and an `alignedat` environment on the right. Then, enclose both in a `center` environment to add a bit of whitespace above and below the math-y material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}    % for 'Salmon' color
\newcommand\Salmon{\color{Salmon}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{lipsum}                % filler text

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
$\begin{array}{@{}ccccc@{}} % use 'array', not 'tabular'
      \toprule
      k & x_{k} & y_{k} & x_{k}y_{k} & x_{k}^2 \\
      \cmidrule(l){2-5}
      1 & 0 & 2 & 0\cdot2 & 0^2 \\
      2 & 1 & 3 & 1\cdot3 & 1^2 \\
      3 & 2 & 5 & 2\cdot5 & 2^2 \\
      4 & 3 & 4 & 3\cdot4 & 3^2 \\
      5 & 4 & 6 & 4\cdot6 & 4^2 \\
      \cmidrule(l){2-5}
      \sum & \Salmon 10 & \Salmon 20 & \Salmon 49 & \Salmon 30 \\
      \bottomrule
\end{array}$
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation 
$\begin{alignedat}{2}
      \alpha &= \frac{
      \det\begin{pmatrix}
          \Salmon 30 & \Salmon 49 \\
          \Salmon 10 & \Salmon 20
      \end{pmatrix}}{
      \det\begin{pmatrix}
          \Salmon 30 & \Salmon 10 \\
          \Salmon 10 & 5
      \end{pmatrix}} & 
      \beta &= \frac{
      \det\begin{pmatrix}
          \Salmon 49 & \Salmon 10 \\
          \Salmon 20 & 5
      \end{pmatrix}}{
      \det\begin{pmatrix}
          \Salmon 30 & \Salmon 10 \\
          \Salmon 10 & 5
      \end{pmatrix}} \\
      &= \frac{30\cdot20-10\cdot49}{30\cdot5-10\cdot10} 
      &\hspace{1cm} % insert horizontal whitespace
      &= \frac{49\cdot5-20\cdot10}{30\cdot5-10\cdot10} \\
      &= 2.2 & &= 0.9
\end{alignedat}$
\end{center}

\lipsum[1][1-7] % filler text
    
\end{document}
```